# .NET library for computing geolocations excluding Windows Phone Library

Tags: c#, .net, geolocation

Windows Phone has a GeoLocation class but I need something for non-phone C# project. I am at the stage where I am ready to start writing my own class. Anyone had experience?

Comment: From the msdn documentation it is available on a non-phone machine.  You need the class on the non-phone for code development.  It is only available according to the documentation on Windows 8.X.  You can get latitude and longitude from google map API.

Answer (score 0):

IP2Location has an IP address based .NET [geolocation](https://www.ip2location.com/software/dot-net-component) component. You can get country, region, city, latitude, longitude, ZIP code, ISP, domain name, timezone, connection speed, IDD code, area code, weather station code, weather station name, MCC, MNC, mobile brand name, elevation and usage type using IP address.

http://www.ip2location.com/software/dot-net-component